# Entrance character from keyboard

Tags: assembly, ias

I am writing exams.I have looked everywhere on the internet, into my book also but nowhere can I find an answer about his question. My teacher question is "Entrance character from keyboard" . I read the book title computer organization and architecture by William Stalling  but I did not find any answer in theory. How can answer this question, he asks it the most of the times.I check wiki but nothing.I don't think is this the answer. I would like to help me if you know.

Comment: “Entrance character from keyboard” is not a question, much less a complete sentence. I am a bit confused as to what you are asking for.

Comment: entry character from keyboard

Comment: Perhaps the word you are looking for is “enter.” However, I am still not sure what the question is supposed to be. Yes, you can use a keyboard to enter characters. What is the actual question?

Comment: its funny man but this is .I have read von neuman everyhting ,and this is the quesiton to write about enter character from keyboard.I know i can enter characters from keyboard may he needs the way i did.May needs bits .I really dont know i wanted to ask to him but he get trip and now i give exams.This is it.Is the only question i dont know

Comment: It is not even a question! I am still not sure what you want to know. Try to rephrase your question in the form “How do I ...?” or “What is ...?” Also, if this has anything to do with assembly, I need to know what architecture and operating system you are programming for.

Comment: i dont programming i have to read about structure CPU ,in memory,out memory about  system RAID.

Comment: Then a) why is your question tagged [assembly] and b) what is it that you actually want to know? So far I've got “write about enter character from keyboard” from you which sounds more like an open-ended creative writing assignment than an actual question. Please do me a favour and try to tell us what your question is, otherwise this is going nowhere.

Comment: this lesson has to do with assembly but is theory part.I want to know because is assembly lesson this what should i answer to show that i know.Example draw the IAS diagram i will draw Enter/Output i will do MDR,IBR,IR,main memory etc.What could i answer how is working the keyboard  if i give a character.Thats what i understand.

Comment: Using the IAS tag is also confusing, because it refers to [the IAS computer](http://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_334741) which didn't even have a keyboard.

Comment: @BoPersson I added the IAS tag because that is what he said in the comment. The references to MDR,IBR,IR,main memory etc also suggest he's being taught about IAS. How the keyboard fits into IAS is beyond me as it doesn't make much sense in this context. We've had some recent IAS questions here on SO so another one doesn't seem unexpected.